# Trying to apply RoundedCornerExtender to Table makes Table flash and vanish

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I've been charged with prototyping a website that has, among other things, a section for "News of the Day", which is user-editable content.

I'm using a Master Page and the default page for the site has a few divs for the various "front page" things they want displayed.  In the 'newstoday" div, I have a table with an embedded ListView in one of the cells to display all valid entries in the database and this worked fine.

They want things to look prettier and suggested rounded corners on panels, like you see in iGoogle.  So I found out that AJAX has built-in stuff for this and went about installing and updating things.

However, when I apply the "RoundedCornersExtender" to the table (like I saw in an example online) the contents of the table flash briefly on the screen and then vanish - or more accurately are hidden behind content from the divs after that (footer, security info, etc).

What I added was:

> ```
> <cc1:RoundedCornersExtender ID="tblNews_RoundedCornersExtender" runat="server" Radius="5"
>     TargetControlID="tblNews" Enabled="True" Color="Navy">
> </cc1:RoundedCornersExtender>
> ```

Among other attempts, I put the table inside a panel and that partially worked - giving me rounded top and bottom borders, but nothing on the sides - I suspect because the panel was taking the entire width of the div instead of being sized by the table inside (different issue but I'll deal with that later).

So if I target the RCE to the panel, it half-works, but if I do it to the table, it doesn't work and turns the table into a 'flasher'.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what browsers is this occuring in? And do you have an online sample we can hit?

Comment: IE7 - and it's an internal site under development on a military base - not exactly public :)

Comment: heh and you need to make it look good for that? Gotta love our tax dollars at work;-) I'm just kidding with you. If I come up with anything I'll letr you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a couple of projects that use the RoundedCornerExtender, and I recall it being finicky on anything other than a Panel. It may have just been my setup, but if I didn't have the BackColor setting on the panel set to the appropriate color, it didn't draw correctly (it didn't like me setting the back color via CSS).

With that said, I didn't have to do anything else special to get it working on the Panel, so I'd probably keep going with the Panel sizing and see if that clears it up.

Comment: Having a panel dedicated to the "rounded top" and a panel for the "data" was the trick.